# Link to top of list

Tags: html, css

I have an html page with several lists nested within one parent list. I want to create a link at the bottom of each list that when clicked will take the user to the top of the list item.

I understand that it is possible to create a link to the top of the page like this:

```
<a href="#">Top of Page</a>
```

An example of what I'm looking for would be

```
<a href=" ">Top of List</a>
```

Comment: And where is the problem? `href="#element_id"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `href` can point to whatever the `id` of your list is.

So, if you have

```
<ul id="MyList">
     <li>Example one</li>
     <li>Example two</li>
     <li>etc...</li>
</ul>
```

you could link to it with:

```
<a href="#MyList">Top of list</a>
```

The initial example you give, linking to "#" jumps to the top of the page, because that's essentially an unused id, which will always go to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `#` symbol to reference ids:

```
<ul id="firstlist">
     <!-- List goes here -->
</ul>

<a href="#firstlist">Go to top</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

use `<a name="name">` tag

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mostafaznv/vzCvN/)

```
<li>list  </li>
<li> list </li>
<li> list </li>
<li> list </li>
<li> list </li>
<li> list </li>
<li> list </li>
<li> <a name="name"> here </a></li>
<li> list </li>
<li> list </li>
<a href="#name">go to top</a>
```

Comment: You can use ID rather than NAME these days, which saves unnecessary tags.

Comment: this was an example my programmer friend ;)

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin see this : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_a_name